# React properties are undefined in child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, properties, state

I have a global state variable that I store and call with Redux:

```
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
  const {loading, error, products} = productList
```

parts of this variable are given to an array:

```
const slideArr = [products[0], products[1], products[2]]
```

I send this array to a component where I want to use it. In order to prevent undefined error I use the following logic:

```
 {loading ? (
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : error ? (
                <h2>{error}</h2>
            ) : (
            <>
          {
          <Carousel array={slideArr}/>
            }       
            </>
          )}
```

Desipte this, in the component array.map function gives an undefined error:

```
props.array.map((img) => ( 
            <img src={img.image} alt={img}
            ))
```

The component shouldn't be rendered until the array is avaible.

Comment: It is because you are getting it from a service potentially so on the first render it is undefined replace array={slideArr} with array={slideArr ?? []}

Comment: That will also give undefined.

Comment: Your map function will not throw an undefined error, but as to why your products are undefined you will need to share more of your code like how you are putting it in redux

Comment: It does give undefined. Redux works fine when I don't use it for components. The code also works when I just give products to the component.